# Reported speech with two parts

Tags: sentence-construction, reported-speech, imperative-sentences

When we turn direct reported speech into indirect reported speech, the rules are different depending on whether the speech is an imperative or a statement.

> Direct: He told her "Turn right at the stoplight and go straight for
> two blocks."
>
> Indirect: He told her to turn right at the stoplight and go straight
> for two blocks.

And

> Direct: He told her "The supermarket is on the right and you can't miss it. "
>
> Indirect: He told her that the supermarket was on the right and she couldn't miss it.

But how do I combine the two indirect reported forms into one, using one reporting verb (tell) when one is an imperative and the other is a statement?

> He told her to turn right at the stoplight and go straight for two
> block, the supermarket was on the right and she couldn't miss it.

Is this sentence grammatical/idiomatic?

Comment: I'd say "the supermarket would be on the/her right". It's hypothetical because he didn't know if she was going to follow his directions..

Comment: Better to start a new sentence than to try to combine 'told her to' and 'told her that' in the same one.

Comment: "He told her to turn right at the stoplight and go straight for two blocks, that the supermarket was on the right and she couldn't miss it."

Comment: I think you made a rod for your own back by arbitrarily ***backshifting*** the second example. Which is fine if that's *all* he told her, but it becomes a bit clunky with longer text being reported. *He told her to turn right at the stoplight and go straight for two blocks, **[and] that** the supermarket **is** on the right and she **can't** miss it* seems better to me.